# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show full address (new Places SDK)

Tags: google-places-api, autocompletetextview

I migrated from the old Places SDK to the new Places SDK (including writing a new adapter), and now when typing an address into my AutoCompleteTextView it shows only the Place Names in the drop-down list (i.e. addresses but without city, state, country), but I need it to show the full address.

Here is my adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.AutocompleteSessionToken;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.RectangularBounds;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.TypeFilter;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;

import java.util.List;

public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapterNew extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable

{
    PlacesClient placesClient;
    AutocompleteSessionToken token;
    private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

    private List<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;
    private List<AutocompletePrediction> tempResult;
    Context context;
    private String  TAG="PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter";
    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapterNew(Context context,PlacesClient placesClient,AutocompleteSessionToken token) {
        super(context,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1);
        this.context=context;
        this.placesClient=placesClient;
        this.token=token;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    mResultList = getAutoComplete(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        // The API successfully returned results.
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;

            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                // when clicked.
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private List<AutocompletePrediction> getAutoComplete(CharSequence constraint){
        // Create a new token for the autocomplete session. Pass this to FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest,
        // and once again when the user makes a selection (for example when calling fetchPlace()).
        AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
        // Create a RectangularBounds object.


        // Use the builder to create a FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.
        FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                // Call either setLocationBias() OR setLocationRestriction().
                //.setLocationBias(bounds)
                //.setLocationRestriction(bounds)
                .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                .setSessionToken(token)
                .setQuery(constraint.toString())
                .build();

        placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse response) {
                for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : response.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString());
                }
                tempResult=response.getAutocompletePredictions();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                }
            }
        });
        return tempResult;
    }
}
```

How can I show the full addresses in the drop-down list?

getAutoComplete is returning tempResult. This is a List that contains fullText (the full address), primaryText (just the address without city, state, country), and other items. So the fullText is what I want, which is being returned, but the primaryText is what is being displayed in the AutoCompleteTextView. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line:

```
textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
```

to this:

```
textView1.setText(item.getFullText(STYLE_BOLD));
```